# ComboBox AutoComplete can't detect

Tags: .net, vb.net

In winform, I have a ComboBox with

```
DropDownStyle=ComboBoxStyle.Simple 
AutoCompleteMode=AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
```

I need to detect whether this ComboBox is expanded (AutoCompleteList is shown).

Comment: Why do you need to detect this? What are you *actually* trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Check [`DroppedDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.droppeddown.aspx) property

```
if (comboBox1.DroppedDown)
   ....
```

Comment: That will tell you if the Combo Box drop down box is displayed, which is distinct from the auto completion box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [ComboBox.DroppedDown Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.droppeddown.aspx)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the combo box is displaying
>   its drop-down portion.

Something like

```
if(comboBox1.DroppedDown)
{
   //your code
}
```

Comment: AutoComplete list is different from DropDownList.